# d3 interaction between map symbol and a legend box

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a map with circles with different colors based on different data values. The map comes with legend boxes each of which has a range of values. I am trying to figure out how to connect these two - when a map circle is clicked, I'd like to highlight the corresponding legend box. Right now, my click function highlightLegend() looks like this and it highlights all boxes when I click a circle:

```
circleColorMap.forEach(function(d, i){
        legend.classed("legend-highlight", function(d) {
            var colorVal = circleColorMap[i].value;

        return colorVal >= id.roll_pm25;
        });
    });`
```

[Here](http://codepen.io/kaz-a/pen/oxxxyX?editors=0010) is the code. I know it has something to do with line 172, but I am not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this entirely by matching colors:

```
  //highlight a legend box that corresponds to a clicked map circle 
  function highlightLegend(id) {
    var self = d3.select(this),
        rects = d3.selectAll('.symbols>svg>rect');
    // clear previous selection
    rects.style({'stroke': 'none', 'stroke-width': '1px'});
    // loop and hightlight matches
    rects.each(function(){
      var r = d3.select(this);
      if (r.style('fill') === self.style('fill')){
        r.style({'stroke': 'red', 'stroke-width': '2px'});
      }
    });
  };
```

Updated [code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqmGpj?editors=1010).

Comment: This is great! Thank you!!